# Are Shimano R440 road flat bar shifters compatible with a mountain bike front derailleur?

Tags: derailleur, shimano, shifter, compatibility

The Shimano shifter flat bar series have the same cable pull length than the mountain bike shifters.

Is this series compatible with a mountain bike front derailleur, Deore, for example?

Answer (score 2):

There's a great thread [here](http://www.bentrideronline.com/messageboard/archive/index.php/t-55536.html) that describes some of this. Here's the meat of it though:

> Shimano's assertion that you need to use "flat-bar" front derailleurs
>   with "flat-bar" shifters is false.
>
> When working with Shimano, "flat-bar" shifters are really just
>   mountain-bike shifters in different colors. This doesn't make a
>   difference for the rear derailleur (Shimano has standardized the cable
>   pull across all of their shifters), but there's two different cable
>   pulls for the front derailleurs. "Road" front derailleurs require less
>   cable movement than "mountain" front derailleurs for the same amount
>   of lateral cage movement.
>
> This has a couple consequences:
>
> 1: operating a "mountain" front
>   derailleur with a "road" shifter will result in insufficient cage
>   movement to make the shift. This is rare in the recumbent world.
>
> 2: operating a "road" front derailleur with a "mountain" shifter will
>   result in the shifter jamming before the internal ratchet catches,
>   meaning the chain will shift but immediately return to its starting
>   position. In other words, the shift fails. If the shift succeeds,
>   often the shifter will jam at that spot and not allow the shift in the
>   other direction. This is very common in the recumbent world.
>
> 1. the longer pull of the "flat-bar" or "mountain" front derailleurs makes for lighter pull at the shifter when using SRAM twist-grip
>      shifters. This can be an advantage for people with slippery hands
>      and/or weaker hands.
>
> "Flat-bar" front derailleurs also have cages that better match the
>   larger diameter chainrings typically installed on road bikes.
>   "Mountain" chainrings are typically smaller, and trying to get a
>   "mountain" front derailleur to work on larger chainrings often
>   involves compromised adjustment or hand-modified cages.
>
> My favorite "flat-bar" front derailleur is the Shimano FD-R443. (This
>   is roughly Sora/Tiagra level parts: cheap, durable, and relatively
>   attractive.) It's since been superceded by the FD-R453, which has a
>   taller inner plate to match newer Shimano cranksets, but I like the
>   FD-R443 for its greater adaptability to different chainring
>   combinations.
>
> I've been using the FD-R443 on several bikes, operated by Shimano
>   Deore LX and XTR and SRAM Half-Pipe Attack shifters. It's always
>   worked flawlessly.

So no, not really. You might be able to find a combination of gearing, derailleur, and cable pull that will work, but you're probably still better off finding a matching set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, yes!

I try these shifters with a Shimano Alivio front derailleur and it works very well. Rear i have a xt with a 11-32 casette and it works well too.

If somebody wants to upgrade an old bike with 8 speeds shifters, these is a good oportunity.

The Shimano 8 speed r440 road flat bar works with mountain bike front and rear derailleur.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure people have this worked out. I purchased one of these 443 front derailleurs and discovered with my XT shifters it behaved exactly like a standard road and derailleur.

I think what is relevant is that there is a matching Shimano SL-R440 shifter that is flat bar shifter. Based on what I have experienced I have to suggest that it's the shifter in this odd group that does the magic of implementing the correct pull for a road bike derailleur

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Dexos. We recommend all new members take our [tour] to get the best out the site. Cheers